# Apache Camel - Yaml DSL - Expression returning custom datatype

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel kamelets SFTP connect to process files in SFTP. When SFTP Source downloads the file from SFTP server we need to set the file length in the header.

I have used set-header to set the values of file length and it is working except the data type, we are expecting the value of the header to be **LONG** but the simple expression returns the **STRING** data type. How can I return the LONG datatype from simple expression (or any other expressions),

[image: 1]

Is YAML DSL supports result type in simple expression?

[image: 2]

Comment: - set-header:
            name: "file-length"
            simple: "${body.available.longValue}" # Instead of returning STRING how can we set LONG objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use result-type

However, then you need to use the *verbose* syntax to be able to set multiple options on the simple, something like:

```
- set-header:
    name: test
    simple:
      expression: "${body}"
      result-type: "long"
```